# {"message": "Invalid Form Body", "code": 50035}

Tags: python, discord

Please help me with this, been searching for hours now. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
headers = {
    'consent':'true',
    'date_of_birth':'2000-08-05',
    'email':email,
    'password':password,
    'username':username  
}
response = req.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/register', data=headers)
print(response.text)
```

`email` and `password` and username are correctly defined

it then returns me this error

```
{"message": "Invalid Form Body", "code": 50035}.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

I tried changing data to json and it came back with a different error. I want it to execute the api.

Comment: `'true'` should probably be `True`.

Comment: `data=headers` should be `json=headers`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an issue with this code snippet

The consent field seems to be missing in the payload of the post request, this field might be mandatory in discord API endpoint, so you should include it.

The data argument should not be used when passing headers to the requests.post() method. Instead, you should use the headers argument.

Here is the modified version of the code:

```
headers = {
    'consent':'true',
    'date_of_birth':'2000-08-05',
    'email':email,
    'password':password,
    'username':username  
}
response = req.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/register', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Please keep in mind that this code may work only if the endpoint accepts the payload you're providing in the headers, also keep in mind that this code is not handling the errors that might happen like network problems, invalid email/password, or other issues. You should add some error handling in the code to handle such cases.

Also, this will only work if you've implemented the logic for getting the email, password, username variables, you need to initialize the variables email, password, username with valid values before using them in the headers.

You might also need to check the discord API documentation to confirm the endpoint URL and its requirements to use the API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks alot, seems to solve my main issue, thanks.